# Angular Test Cannot read property 'ngModule' of null

Tags: angular, testng

I'm trying to use a simple test on Angular, here is the content of the test :

```
import { ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser"
import { TestComponentComponent } from './test-component.component';

fdescribe('TestComponentComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponentComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponentComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should show no data', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const noDataDiv = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#noData'));
    expect(noDataDiv.nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('No Data');
  });
});
```

i run the test by this command :

**ng test --main .\src\app\test-component\test-component.component.spec.ts**

and i got this error :

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngModule' of null**

is there any change between the version ?

i'm using the latest version of angular and the test file has been generated with command ng generate component

i've just add the 'f' behind the describe and the latest 'it'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need the `--main` parameter, you can just run the file with include:

```
ng test --include src/app/test-component/test-component.component.spec.ts
```

Include also has [glob](https://angular.io/cli/test) support, which you can use to run tests in a folder:

```
ng test --include src/**/*.spec.ts
```

**What is the `--main` parameter for?**

It is used to define the entrypoint of the Angular app for Karma. This is important because Angular needs to boot up a in testing mode, so that e.g. Modules and Components can be created.

If you look at the `angular.json` in your project, you will see something like this:

```
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts"
            ...
          }
        }
```

The `main` identifier is linked to the file `src/test.ts`, which initializes the test environment:

```
// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
```

So one use case for `--main` would be to have different entrypoint files for different kinds of tests that require special configuration for the testing environment.